# HTML: fullscreen 2x2 table with shrank/stretched (but correct ratio) image in every cell

Tags: html, css, image, html-table

I would like to create a full-screen (so to fill the visible area) 2x2 table, where every cell contains a center aligned image, which size is adjusted to the cell (shrink/stretched), that way that it's ratio is kept.
Maybe an image is better:

[image]

What I found so far:

2x2 full-screen table HTML:

```
<table style="height:100%;width:100%; position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;border:1px solid">
 <tr style="height: 50%;">
   <td style="width: 50%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"></td>
   <td style="width: 50%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr style="height: 50%;">
    <td style="width: 50%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"></td>
    <td style="width: 50%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I tried to add image in the cells, like:

```
<img style="width: 100%;max-height: 100%" src="...">
```

This is almost ok: 
It stretches horizontally to fill the cell, but the height it too large this case, so table won't fit on the screen, vertical scrollbar appears.
Also it shrinks horizontally to fill the cell, but the height it too large this case, so table won't fit on the screen, vertical scrollbar appears.

So it is ok for width changes, but not considering the situation when height should be the leader.

Basically, I would like a full-screen 2x2 gallery viewer, that every image fills as much as possible the cell, keeping the ratio.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that using a `<table>` is not compulsory? I have created an example using 4 divs. Clean, simple.

The markup is reduced to:

```
<div class="section">Section 1 image</div>
<div class="section">Section 2 image</div>
<div class="section">Section 3 image</div>
<div class="section">Section 4 image</div>
```

### The basic CSS

- Sections are `display: inline-block` with 50% height and width.
- The images have 100% height and will keep the height/width ratio correct
- `box-sizing: border-box` incorporates the borders into the width / height of the sections
- `html, body { height: 100%; }` allows the sections to have a 50% height
- The body is given an appropriate min-width to prevent the sections from becoming too small along with a max-width
- To prevent double borders, the appropriate sections are targeted with `nth-child` / `first-child` and have a border removed

## New Example

`max-width` and `max-height` maintains the aspect ratio of the image when resized vertically and horizontally

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.section {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}
.section:first-child,
.section:nth-child(3) {
  border-right: none;
}
.section:nth-child(1),
.section:nth-child(2) {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.section img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 90%;
  max-width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
</div><div class="section">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
</div><div class="section">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
</div><div class="section">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
</div>
```

---

### Archived - broken - Examples

"Show code snippet" and then run it.

Note how the closing and opening div tags have no whitespace between them. This is to [prevent the gap that occurs between inline elements](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

### Example 1

The images are `position: absolute` and position themselves in relation to their section container which has `position: relative`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.section {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}
.section:first-child,
.section:nth-child(3) {
  border-right: none;
}
.section:nth-child(1),
.section:nth-child(2) {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.section img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
</div><div class="section">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
</div><div class="section">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
</div><div class="section">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
</div>
```

### Example 2

Images are not `position:absolute` and are centered with padding and `text-align: center`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 99%;
}
body {
  min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.section {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
}
.section:nth-child(1),
.section:nth-child(2) {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.section:first-child,
.section:nth-child(3) {
  border-right: none;
}
.section img {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
</div><div class="section">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
</div><div class="section">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
</div><div class="section">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It is quite good, but not 100%. I save the html and css into files, and opened in firefox, and when resizing the browser horizontally, when the width of the cells become narrower than the image, the images are not shrank. Only vertically resizing works when shrinking.

Comment: Thank you very much. I made a "screenshot", but I see you got what I meant :) http://oi59.tinypic.com/504i9k.jpg

Comment: @Zoli - How does [this example look to you](http://jsbin.com/giropu/1/edit) - using max-width and max-height on the image.

Comment: Very good, this works now, thanks! Now one thing is missing: it does not stretch the image to make it bigger. Like replace the image with "placehold.it/100". Even if I make the browser big, they remain 100x100, instead of matching their cell size.

Comment: That's a bit tricky - I think the only way to achieve that is to apply a "small" class to smaller images which you need to blow up a little and give them a percentage min-height. [Like this example here.](http://jsbin.com/hekiwi/1/edit). It's a balancing act.

Comment: Problem is that I don't know these images beforehand, they are generated dynamically. Also, I don't know the screen resolution, so "smaller image" can be small on a device, but large on an other one.

Comment: @Zoli - Do you have any control over the images when they are imported? Could you only accept images that are, say, at least 400px in height or width? Or, could you resize the actual image file to a larger width on input? The larger the images are, the better the look will be... the example above easily scales down.

Comment: Well, actually I could do that. Probably then the best way is to have only larger images than the allowed minimum cell size, and then we are done, as shrinking works.